# Append Adsence code with jquery

Tags: jquery, adsense

I have adsense code and i want to append it to a div with jquery

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXX" data-ad-slot="XXXXX" data-ad-format="auto"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

But it breaks all my script ,
I am doing like this :

```
var script ='<?php echo preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",html_entity_decode($jobsideads[0]['script'])); ?>';
jQuery(script).appendTo('#tab1');
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run PHP code in the script?

Comment: because the adsence code is set in database from backend

Comment: PHP is precompiled before the page loads; javascript is only run after or on page load. Your javascript/jQuery will literally be sending the line "<?php echo..." as a string, not to mention you are using single quotes around 'script'.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in this code

```
var script ='<?php echo preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",html_entity_decode($jobsideads[0]['script'])); ?>';
jQuery(script).appendTo('#tab1');
```

change it to

```
var script ='<?php echo preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",html_entity_decode($jobsideads[0]["script"])); ?>';
jQuery('#tab1').append(script);
```